# How to make IK Multimedia Stealth Plug work on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I used Wine and I have Amplitube set up on my labtop but I can't get the Stealth Plug drivers to work on Ubuntu. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me very well.. in Ubuntu 12.04 just "plug and play" after plug in, in sound settings check "Stealthplug no bass boost" and MUST RESTART Machine.

After that is Stealthplug the main system audio card (ALSA) and work fine with Qjack, Qsynth, Qtractor (this chain of startups is a must...) and the Qsynth hosts Soundfonts (.Sf2 files), that are many good quality and free!

After my first tests also in good audio sync with MIDI (must say that I use Stealthplug only as input and output card without any VST or ASIO advantages - have my own hardware based guitar multieffect gear - KORG AX3000G).

At last but not least, Qtractor is so NICE simple, that I could now after years of seeing "complicated" workspaces of innovatives massive DAWs, really see simple windows, that suggest me those "little displays" of my beloved hardware of the 80's and I can now again put importance on "HOW IT SOUNDS" and No "How it looks like".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it could work in a wine environment. You should use linux specific software like Jackd and Ardour. Maybe you should try ubuntu studio distribution that includes both of them, a realtime kernel, and many others audio software.